# Would one be able to transfer a home edition to a replacement machine/laptop?

Tags: version-10, mac-os-x, licensing, home-edition

I presently have Version 10.0.1.0 installed on my home MacBookAir, and 
am considering updating. The laptop is more than four years old, and I am
a little concerned that I may, at some point, need a replacement to it (although it presently seems fine). If I did acquire such a replacement would I have to repurchase a home edition--or could it be transferred?

Comment: Is this the answer: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12412?

Comment: In practice, you would fill the System Transfer Form in the User Portal, and they would give you necessary information for license transfer between systems. I think I have done this several times in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but it is still not clear to me whether or not the  transfer would require an additional/new purchase fee.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but it is still not clear to me yet whether or not the  transfer would require an additional/new purchase fee. If a new fee would be required, then it would be nice to have some sense of how much confidence I should have in my laptop's continuing longevity.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater, if you have a current license, you do not have to do a new purchase. Just contact to Wolfram Support to participate them your hardware update. That happened to me in the past, and I had not any problem. Also, take into account the link that Kuba provided...

Comment: I received the following reply from the Mathematica staff: "If/when you get a new computer you will be able to transfer your current license. No need to purchase an entirely new one."